# Why doesn't Blackberry Hub+ Calendar update events with given UID?

Tags: blackberry

When importing an .ics, the UID is imported as [UID_2445](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#UID_2445) so that following updates for this event can be related to the original event.

However, such following updates are then not applied to the existing event, but Blackberry Hub+ Calendar just seems to create another local event with the same UID_2445.

Did I oversee something?

Original use case + steps to reproduce:

- Invitation for a meeting (UID:abcd) is received as .ics over email
- Invitation is imported with Blackberry Hub+ Calendar. UID is processed correctly and UID_2445 set accordingly. (If the calendar is synced with DAVx5, DAVx5 takes the UID + .ics as file name and uploads it to the server. But the problem is also there without DAVx5 sync.)
- An update for the invitation (meeting has been moved to another time or location) is received as .ics over email
- Update is imported with Blackberry Hub+. UID is processed and UID_2445 set again, but Blackberry Hub+ Calendar creates a new event instead of updating the original one. (If the calendar is synced with DAVx5, DAVx5 again takes the UID + .ics as file name and tries to upload it, but there's already the original event with this UID/file name, so the changes are rejected by the server and DAVx5 reverts the update, according to its "server always wins" conflict resolution strategy.)

Why is this, did I overlook something?

Expected result:

After importing the original event + the updated event, there should be only the updated event with the correct UID2445.

Actual result:

After importing the original event + the updated event, there are both the original and updated event in the calendar, both with the same UID2445.